# How do I embed sfDoctrineGuardPlugin register/signup form into my homepage module template?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms, sfdoctrineguard

So far I have copied sfGuardRegister into my frontend app modules directory so it has taken over the default sfGuardRegister located in the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin directory in the symfony plugins directory.

I want to have the plugins sfGuardRegister signup/register form show up on my homepage template..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is all installed properly, you should be able to drop the following code wherever you want to login link to appear:

```
<?php echo link_to("Create Account", "sfApply/apply"); ?>
```

This is assuming you have installed it properly, and have configured your routes according to the install guide.